# Simple movie API request not showing up in the console log

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch-api, console.log

I am trying to make a simple api request to fetch some data for trending movies of the week. I do not see it in the web browser console though. Any suggestions? This is the first API that I have tried on my own. I am a coding bootcamp graduate. Anything thing helps!

here is the repository:https://github.com/JoelGetzke/JoelsMovies

Here is the code:

```
const apiKey = '<API_KEY>';
const apiUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org';

// Example endpoint to get a list of movies
const endpoint = `${apiUrl}/3/trending/movie/week`;

// Constructing the request URL with API key
const requestUrl = `${endpoint}?api_key=${apiKey}`;

// Making a GET request using fetch API
fetch(requestUrl)
  .then(response => {
    // Check if the response is successful (status code 200)
    if (response.ok) {
      // Parse the JSON response
      return response.json();
    }
    // If response is not successful, throw an error
    throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Do something with the data
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle errors
    console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
  });
```

I tried to refresh the page and open up the browser consol.log.  It is currently reading:
index.html:89

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

index.html:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recall exactly how response.json() works but I have a feeling it 'runs' its input as regular JavaScript, which means if the MIME type returned by the server isn't application/javascript then it might not recognise it as runnable code. (Perhaps!)

First, try dumping/inspecting the data you get back from the server to double check it is indeed plain JSON. Then use JSON.parse() instead of response.json() to turn it from a string into an object. If the MIME type is indeed the problem, then JSON.parse() will work so long as you feed it a string, regardless of how the network headers described that string.